# How to download files from git repository?

Tags: git, heroku

So I have few .mp4 files in my heroku repository. And I want to download them to my local repositroy.

I'm doing it like this:

`git pull heroku master`

But it doesn't download the .mp4 files.
How can I get those files?

Comment: They probably aren't part of your repo, nor should they be. They're just on heroku. You'll probably need to get them via plain HTTP (wget, curl).

Comment: Confused. If they are **in your repository** then git pull will fetch 'em (so to speak) Are they on another branch? How did you get them into heroku without hem being on your local repo? Can you use the other remote that did add them to the repo?

Comment: And why are mp4 being version controlled in Git anyway? Git is not very good at storing large binary files. Git is meant for source (text) mostly.

Comment: I was uploading on heroku via git, they are background for the website(https://safe-castle-3835.herokuapp.com/), but i had some pc problems, and had to reinstall a lot of stuff. So I made a new repo, added remote heroku directory, and tried to pull everything, and everything pulled except the videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing git in a new dir should be the best option:

> - If your repo is already initiated, check your remotes: `git remote --v`

```
$ git remote --v
heroku  ssh://xxxxxxxx.xxx:repo.git (fetch)
heroku  ssh://xxxxxxxx.xxx:repo.git (push)
```

> - Check the list you have there. The first parameter, is the remote name, then you should write (in this case, git pull heroku master).
> - If the first name you see there is origin, as it usually is for all of us, you should write: `git pull origin master`
>
> At this moment, you should be able to receive your data if you
>   correctly have your repo configured.
>
> If you now have some error messages about merging, and different
>   versions, maybe you should perform a `git commit -a -m"commit message"` and then try the pull again. At this moment, if there is
>   something to merge, GIT will tell you on screen.
>
> After solving any merge problems, or if you cannot do it in that dir,
>   try to create a new repo with `git init` in a new directory and add
>   your remote repo with `git remote add heroku xxx://xxxxxx.com/repo.git`
>
> After that, just do again the pull, and the full repo will be downloaded

Anyway, here you have some pages about git common problems:

- http://blackbe.lt/common-git-problems-and-solutions/
- https://www.codementor.io/git/tutorial/10-common-git-problems-fix

Hope you can solve it!!